# How to fix json conversion to c# class?

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to generate classes from json to deseralize to c# object but list object is not correct, where am i going wrong? Available rooms should be a list as per my assumption but It does not work.

Below is my JSON

```
{
  "avaliabilitiesResponse": {
    "Hotels": {
      "Hotel": [
        {
          "HotelCode": "0017855",
          "HotelsName": "Hilton Jeddah",
          "Location": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
          "Rating": "4",
          "LowestPrice": "35",
          "Currency": "EUR",
          "IsReady": "true",
          "AvailableRooms": {
            "AvailableRoom": [
              {
                "RoomCode": "11245",
                "RoomName": "Standard",
                "Occupancy": "1",
                "Status": "true"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "12000",
                "RoomName": "Double",
                "Occupancy": "2",
                "Status": "true"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "99685",
                "RoomName": "Twin",
                "Occupancy": "2",
                "Status": "true"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "HotelCode": "0018799",
          "HotelsName": "Ramada Continental Jeddah",
          "Location": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
          "Rating": "3",
          "LowestPrice": "345",
          "Currency": "USD",
          "IsReady": "false",
          "AvailableRooms": {
            "AvailableRoom": [
              {
                "RoomCode": "00012",
                "RoomName": "Triple Standard",
                "Occupancy": "3",
                "Status": "false"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "5477",
                "RoomName": "Triple Sea View",
                "Occupancy": "3",
                "Status": "false"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "996666",
                "RoomName": "Standard Double",
                "Occupancy": "2",
                "Status": "true"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "HotelCode": "0010888",
          "HotelsName": "Qasr Al Sharq",
          "Location": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
          "Rating": "5",
          "LowestPrice": "3500",
          "Currency": "SAR",
          "IsReady": "true",
          "AvailableRooms": {
            "AvailableRoom": {
              "RoomCode": "102432",
              "RoomName": "Suite",
              "Occupancy": "4",
              "Price": "3500",
              "Status": "true"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

it gets converted to c# like this.

```
public class AvailableRooms
{
    public object AvailableRoom { get; set; } //this is not correct i assume, i tried to fix it like Hotels have Hotel in Json to have a list here but it does not work. 
}

public class Hotel
{
    public string HotelCode { get; set; }
    public string HotelsName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    public string LowestPrice { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string IsReady { get; set; }
    public AvailableRooms AvailableRooms { get; set; }
}

public class Hotels
{
    public List<Hotel> Hotel { get; set; }
}

public class AvaliabilitiesResponse
{
    public Hotels Hotels { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public AvaliabilitiesResponse avaliabilitiesResponse { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using Json2csharp as well as visual studio's paste special option for class conversion, I still don't get available rooms in my object.

Comment: You shall post the error also

Comment: In c# I don't see my available object for Rooms. There is no error but I don't see the list of rooms against hotels.

Comment: Your json is wrong, hotels should be an array and not an object, and hotel should be every object of the hotels array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fixed json (problem was the last `AvailableRooms`, which had an invalid member `AvailableRoom` which was both array and object). This JSON can be pasted json-as-classes with visual studio:

```
{
  "avaliabilitiesResponse": {
    "Hotels": {
      "Hotel": [
        {
          "HotelCode": "0017855",
          "HotelsName": "Hilton Jeddah",
          "Location": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
          "Rating": "4",
          "LowestPrice": "35",
          "Currency": "EUR",
          "IsReady": "true",
          "AvailableRooms": 
            [
              {
                "RoomCode": "11245",
                "RoomName": "Standard",
                "Occupancy": "1",
                "Status": "true"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "12000",
                "RoomName": "Double",
                "Occupancy": "2",
                "Status": "true"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "99685",
                "RoomName": "Twin",
                "Occupancy": "2",
                "Status": "true"
              }
            ]
          }
        ,
        {
          "HotelCode": "0018799",
          "HotelsName": "Ramada Continental Jeddah",
          "Location": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
          "Rating": "3",
          "LowestPrice": "345",
          "Currency": "USD",
          "IsReady": "false",
          "AvailableRooms" :  
            [
              {
                "RoomCode": "00012",
                "RoomName": "Triple Standard",
                "Occupancy": "3",
                "Status": "false"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "5477",
                "RoomName": "Triple Sea View",
                "Occupancy": "3",
                "Status": "false"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "996666",
                "RoomName": "Standard Double",
                "Occupancy": "2",
                "Status": "true"
              }
            ]

        },
        {
          "HotelCode": "0010888",
          "HotelsName": "Qasr Al Sharq",
          "Location": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
          "Rating": "5",
          "LowestPrice": "3500",
          "Currency": "SAR",
          "IsReady": "true",
          "AvailableRooms": [
            {
              "RoomCode": "102432",
              "RoomName": "Suite",
              "Occupancy": "4",
              "Price": "3500",
              "Status": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
public class AvailableRooms
{
    public object AvailableRoom { get; set; }
}
```

By:

```
public class AvailableRooms
{
    public Room[] AvailableRoom { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public string RoomCode { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string Occupancy { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Note: for some reason, all room fields are strings. I would expect `int` and `bool` in some places.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Models.Room[]' 
Path 'avaliabilitiesResponse.Hotels.Hotel[2].AvailableRooms.AvailableRoom.RoomCode', line 77, position 25.'

Sorry not working,  I am new to JSON deserialization sorry.

Comment: According to the JSON you posted, `AvailableRoom` is an array. In the error I don't  see that reflected. Can you show what is in line 77 in the actual JSON?

Comment: Line 77     "RoomCode": "102432",

Comment: That part is invalid if you see the other `AvailableRoom`s. Those are all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your JSON object

```
"AvailableRooms": {
            "AvailableRoom": [
              {
                "RoomCode": "11245",
                "RoomName": "Standard",
                "Occupancy": "1",
                "Status": "true"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "12000",
                "RoomName": "Double",
                "Occupancy": "2",
                "Status": "true"
              },
              {
                "RoomCode": "99685",
                "RoomName": "Twin",
                "Occupancy": "2",
                "Status": "true"
              }
            ]
          }
```

`AvailableRooms` is an object here, which has a property called `AvailableRoom` which is an array. Try removing `AvailableRoom` property altogether from your json object and keep the array values under `AvailableRoom`.

If you see your last object in `Hotel` array

```
"AvailableRooms": {
            "AvailableRoom": { // This is an array in the first 2 Hotel objects, but an object here.
              "RoomCode": "102432",
              "RoomName": "Suite",
              "Occupancy": "4",
              "Price": "3500",
              "Status": "true"
            }
          }
```

Comment: Why remove the property if you can fix the serialization?

Comment: because the properties are all other the place, and as per the naming AvailableRooms is supposed to be an array.

Comment: Never mind, I got the problem you pointed to. It just wasn't clear when I read it.

Comment: see the person with accepted answer, that's exactly what I meant to say. But people here want to be spoon fed by getting answer to copy/paste rather than understanding the problem.

Comment: From my point of view, you should have made clear only the last object was wrong. The others are fine. That is why the code (and code generation) fails.

Comment: I don't think that's the right approach though, that will fix the problem but not the best solution for situations like this where all you want is an array not an object with one property in it.

Comment: Do you mean JSON, then yes, it's poorly structured. and that's what I meant to say in my answer. There is a Hotel array within Hotels, instead Hotels should be an array without Hotel. Likewise AvailableRoom shouldn't be there within AvailableRooms.